# Adyen checkout API v49 for Golang library

Tags: api, go, adyen

I'm moving an implementation of the Adyen's Checkout API to Golang.
The problem I have is the ruby implementation is too old and uses Checkout `v49`. I have seen that https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-go-api-library does not support it (it ranges between [v52](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-go-api-library/blob/v0.0.1/src/adyen/api.go#L39) and [v69](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-go-api-library/blob/v6.0.1/src/adyen/api.go#L51)).

Therefore I have 2 questions:

- is there a way to use v49 or am I required to upgrade it?
- while I migrate functionality, if required to upgrade, I should work with 2 versions, hence, are responses backwards compatible between versions?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any mention of older version in [Adyen/adyen-go-api-library](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-go-api-library): upgrading to the latest version is sensible.

Especially considering that, according [to this page](https://help.adyen.com/knowledge/3d-secure/integrate-3ds/how-do-i-update-my-api-version-to-support-3ds2):

> Our newer API endpoints are backward compatible with older versions  (> v40/v41) of the endpoint, so you can expect all current functionalities you are using to continue to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

The Adyen Golang API [v6.0.1](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-go-api-library/releases/tag/v6.0.1) supports Checkout API v69, and it goes as far as v52 - correctly pointed out by you - because it has been created more recently than others (ie Ruby).

It is indeed a good idea to start with the latest available version, you get access to all the features and functionality you need, and it will be easier to find relevant documentation and support.

A good start is to look at the [Adyen Golang Sample](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-golang-online-payments) application that shows how to integrate the library and perform a payment.